# How can I formulate this specific if-then constraint?

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, integer-programming, constraint-programming

IF $\sum\limits_d X_{i,d}\ge6$ THEN $Y_i = 1$ (strictly)

AND

IF $\sum\limits_d X_{i,d}<6$ THEN $Y_i = 0$ (strictly)

$X$ and $Y$ are binary variables.

What I'm actually trying to do is to charge the objective function some value whenever $Y_i = 1$. That is, for each $i$, if $Y_i=1$, the term $C\cdot Y_i$ is charged in the objective function only and only if $\sum\limits_d X_{i,d}\ge6$.

Here are some more details about the problem if needed.

- $I =$ set of workers (a total of 5 workers);
- $D =$ set of days (a total of 6 days);
- $C=$ cost for each worked day is fixed.

**If a worker worked for 6 days, then the cost of the sixth day is double the normal cost i.e. $= 2C$.**

Define $X_{i,d} = 1$ if worker $i$ works on day $d$ and 0 otherwise, so I want to charge the objective function a cost if the sum of $X_{i,d}$ over $d$ equals $6$ for each $i\in I$.

How can introduce such a variable that would charge the objective function?

Comment: Would be so nice to just write $Y_i \gets (\sum_i X_i \geq 6)$ when using a MILP solver.

Comment: [Well](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/py_model_agc_indicator.html), [sure](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/discr_optim/indicator_constr/02_indicators_defn.html) [thing](https://www.scipopt.org/doc-7.0.1/html/cons__indicator_8h.php).

Comment: Thank you very much for the links above, ktnr. @MAHER will surely be interested in using that to avoid the tedious linearization works described below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For simplicity, I will drop the $i$ subscripts everywhere and instead write $x_d$ for $x_{i,d}$ and $y$ for $y_i$.

The linear constraint $$\sum_{d=1}^6 x_d \le 5 + y$$ enforces $$\sum_{d=1}^6 x_d > 5 \implies y=1.$$
You can derive this constraint via conjunctive normal form as follows:
$$
\left(\land_{d=1}^6 x_d\right) \implies y \\
\lnot\left(\land_{d=1}^6 x_d\right) \lor y \\
\left(\lor_{d=1}^6 \lnot x_d\right) \lor y \\
\sum_{d=1}^6 (1-x_d) + y \ge 1 \\
\sum_{d=1}^6 x_d - y \le 5 \\
$$

---

The objective will drive $y=0$ otherwise, but if you want to explicitly enforce it, you can again use conjunctive normal form:
$$
\neg\left(\land_{d=1}^6 x_d\right) \implies \lnot y \\
\left(\land_{d=1}^6 x_d\right) \lor \lnot y \\
\land_{d=1}^6 (x_d \lor \lnot y) \\
x_d + (1 - y) \ge 1 \quad \text{for $d\in\{1,\dots,6\}$} \\
x_d \ge y \quad \text{for $d\in\{1,\dots,6\}$}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! you are amazing! you made it sound too easy.

Comment: Just for future readers of this question, note that this enforces the "if" part but not the "only if" (sum less than 6 implies $y = 0$). From the context of the original question, $y=1$ increases a cost that is presumably being minimized, so the solver will set $y=0$ whenever it is allowed to.

Comment: @prubin I added the converse just now.

Comment: @RobPratt So when formulating the problem all constraints should be put together !? 

The way i see it is that if the following is added xi+(1−yi)≥1for i∈{1,…,6}xi≤yifor i∈{1,…,6}

It goes against the first formulation ∑i=16xi−yi≤5 . 

Please correct if I'm wrong. I'm still learning.

Comment: The point raised by @prubin is that you could have $y_i=1$ even if all $x_i=0$.  The objective discourages that, but it is still feasible unless you explicitly prevent it, as I did in my updated answer.

Comment: By the way, the sum should be over $d$ in the desired rule.  You want, for each worker $i$, to enforce $\sum_d x_{i,d} \ge 6 \implies y_i=1$.

Comment: I just saw this. It's correct now for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

I thought about the following:

then all you need is:
$$
Y \ge (\sum X_d) - 5 \ \ \& \ \ Y \le (\sum X_d)/5.
$$
This can be written in a solver:

$\forall$ worker $i$, you can just add $Cy_i$ to the cost function and add the constraint $$ \sum_{d=1}^6 x_{id} \leq 5 + y_i$$.

(Note that $y_i$ can be declared as either continuous or binary.)